# Calculating the total number of given day (i.e sunday or monday or etc) in a given year in C language

Tags: c, calendar

As title clears it i want to count the total number of given day in a given year range between 1600-2500 in c language. I have written some code but stucked in counting leap year days. Please help me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int calculateNoOfDays(int year,int choice);
int isLeap(int year);

int main()
{
    int choice,year;    
    int count;
    char dayName[12];

     do{
         printf("Please Enter a year between 1601 and 2500\n");
         scanf("%d",&year);
     }
     while(!(year>=1601 && year<=2500));


 printf("Please select an option between 1 and 7: \nMonday: 1\nTuesday: 2\nWednesday: 3\nThursday: 4\nFriday: 5\nSaturday: 6\nSunday: 7\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);


    switch((choice))
    {

            case 1:strcpy(dayName,"Monday");
    break;
        case 2:strcpy(dayName,"Tuesday");
    break;
    case 3:strcpy(dayName,"Wednesday");
    break;
    case 4:strcpy(dayName,"Thursday");
    break;
    case 5:strcpy(dayName,"Friday");
    break;
    case 6:strcpy(dayName,"Saturday");
    break;
    case 7:strcpy(dayName,"Sunday");
    break;

}

count=calculateNoOfDays(year,choice);
printf("For the given year, the number of %ss in that year is: %d \n",dayName,count);

return (1);
}
```

Comment: What does your `calculateNoOfDays()` look like?

Comment: Also, note that you should `return 0` from `main` to indicate success.

Comment: To continue with the "nagging" about `main` by @Lstor, you should also always make the argument `void` for functions taking no arguments. Otherwise in C the function is specified as taking an unknown number of unknown arguments.

Comment: sounds like a problem from project euler C: . use mktime(3p) and iterate over the  days and test for mondays and sundays

Comment: @Kira You definitely don't need to iterate over all the days (see my answer).  Some iteration might be needed to get to Jan 1st of the year of interest, but after that the answer is no more than one subtraction and one `int` division (by 7) away.

Comment: @meaning-matters :O I see

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) it's quite easy to determine which years are leap.  Here's the pseudocode:

```
if year is divisible by 400 then
   is_leap_year
else if year is divisible by 100 then
   not_leap_year
else if year is divisible by 4 then
   is_leap_year
else
   not_leap_year
```

With that you got the number of days in a year: 365 or 366.

Next step would be to determine on what weekday Jan 1 falls.  This should be doable by fiddling with the standard [C date/time library functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_date_and_time_functions).  You may need to do some iteration to get there, but perhaps none if you are smart.

What's left then is a simple calculation to get to your number of days.

Comment: if i input 2013 and enter the day 1 then it should count how many mondays are there in year 2013